# How to keep delay of 10 seconds after each submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Javascript below

And want to do it in   working in FireFox 
I wanted to keep 5 seconds delay after each submit

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function sleep(ms)
    {
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + ms);
        while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
    }

function test() {
var windowCounter = 1; 
var myStringArray = [ "user1", "user2" , "user3" , "user4" ]
var len = myStringArray.length;
for (var i=0; i<3; ++i) {
document.inform.cid = myStringArray[i];
document.inform.pwd = "xxxxxxxx";
   document.inform.target = windowCounter++; // a different target each time
    document.inform.submit();
}
}
</script>
 </head>
 <body >
  <form name="inform"   target="newWin" action="https://www.google.co.in/">
<input type="text" name="cid"  />
<input type="hidden" name="pwd"  />
 <input type="hidden" name="throttle" value="999" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="test()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have tried keeping sleep manually after each submit and tried using setTimeOut , but nothing is working .

could anybody please help me

**Edited Part**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var interval = window.setInterval(iterate, 5000);
var myStringArray = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"];

  function iterate() {
 iterate.arr = iterate.arr || myStringArray.slice(0);

    //if it still has elements left
    if(iterate.arr.length > 0) {
        document.inform.cid = iterate.arr.pop(); //remove the top one
alert(document.inform.cid);
        document.inform.pw = "xxxx";
        document.inform.target = iterate.arr.length; // a different target each time - length of the arr
        document.inform.submit();
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(interval); //no more left cancel it
    }
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="inform" method="get"  target="newWin" action="https://www.google.co.in/">
  <input type="text" name="cid" />
<input type="password" name="pw" />
<input type="hidden" name="throttle" value="999" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="iterate()"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The function is setTimeout not setTimeOut.

Comment: setTimeout(function () {
  document.inform.target = windowCounter++; // a different target each time
                document.inform.submit();
        }, 5000);

Comment: why are you not calling your sleep function??

Comment: It is _never_ a good idea to write a loop-based sleep/pause function in JavaScript - while the function is running the browser will not repaint or respond to user input. You should restructure your code to use `setTimeout()`. Also, what's that `.pwd = "xxxxxxxx"` about? If the password is supposed to be secret you can't include it in your JS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use something like (not tested though):

```
    var interval = window.setInterval(iterate, 5000);
    var myStringArray = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"];

function iterate() {
    iterate.arr = iterate.arr || myStringArray.slice(0); //set a private array to cache

    //if it still has elements left
    if(iterate.arr.length > 0) {
    //thought there was more than one formon the page - but if only one then we can reference by its name - cid

        ///:document.inform.cid = iterate.arr.pop(); //remove the top one
    iterate.arr.pop();
        document.inform.pwd = "xxxxxxxx";
        document.inform.target = iterate.arr.length; // a different target each time - length of the arr
        document.inform.submit();
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(interval); //no more left cancel it
    }


};
```

Comment: That array caching code just creates another reference to the same array, so when you do `iterate.arr.pop()` it will be removing elements from `myStringArray`. For an independent copy of the array use `iterate.arr = iterate.arr || myStringArray.slice(0);`

Comment: I replaced it with iterate.arr = iterate.arr || myStringArray.slice(0); , but still its not populating in the alert

Comment: Where are alerting? Can you post a quick snippet?

Comment: If there is only one form take a look at the edit above. You probably can optimize it even more by caching your selectors (ref to form)

Answer (score 0):

Plaese try This:

```
<html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function submit()
        {
             document.inform.submit();
        }

    function test() {
     setTimeout('submit()',5000);
     }
    </script>
     </head>
     <body >
      <form name="inform"  target="newWin"  action="https://www.google.co.in/">
    <input type="text" name="cid"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="pwd"  />
     <input type="hidden" name="throttle" value="999" />
        <input type="button" value="go" onclick="test()">
      </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```